# Is Mathematica computing the conditional expectation correctly?

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions, conditional

Given a simple case of say 2 independent trials each with probability of success 1/3. Consider a random variable that is gives the 3 times the total successes.

We can define this random variable in terms of predefined distributions by simply setting it as `3 x BinomialDistribution[2,1/3]`.

I want to calculate the expected value of this variable given atleast one success which I try to calculate as follows:

```
Expectation[x\[Conditioned](x>0),x\[Distributed]TransformedDistribution[3x,x\[Distributed]BinomialDistribution[2,1/3.]]]
```

But this gives a weird answer

> 10.6592

Even if i remove the zeros of this distribution its mean cannot be larger than the max value of the variable which is 6 in this case.

The answer I expect can be achieved using:

```
Expectation[3x\[Conditioned](3x>0),x\[Distributed]BinomialDistribution[2,1/3.]]
```

So the `TransformedDistribution` is bugging right?

---

```
{
    PDF[TransformedDistribution[3x,x\[Distributed]BinomialDistribution[2,1/3.]],x],
    PDF[BinomialDistribution[2,1./3],x/3]
}//FullSimplify
```

[image]

Both are producing the same crazy PDF, there are no `Boole[...]` to set non-integer values to zero.

Comment: Yeah I think it is bugging indeed, perhaps you can use:
Expectation[3 x \[Conditioned] (x > 0), x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[2, 1/3.]]

Comment: It would appear so, look at the PDF of your transformed distribution over the range of zero to six : it has crazy values, and sums to >1

Comment: @ciao both the transformed and untransformed distribution have crazy PDFs, see the updated question.

Comment: The PDF might look crazy but it gives the right values (and sums to 1).  I think it must be that the `Expectation` function doesn't handle things properly.  Using the "definition" given in the documentation, the following works:  `d = TransformedDistribution[3 x, 
  x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[2, 1/3]]; 
Expectation[Piecewise[{{z, z > 0}}], z \[Distributed] d]/
 Probability[z > 0, z \[Distributed] d]`.

Comment: The following also works:  `Expectation[3 x \[Conditioned] x > 0, 
 x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[2, 1/3]]`.

Comment: @JimB - it sums to 1 for what should be the support, but sums to >1 over the range.

Comment: @ciao You are correct. But if I can offer a feeble defense: `Sum[PDF[d, z], {z, 0, n}]` sums to 1 for any finite value for `n`.  It only chokes when one plugs in $\infty$.

Comment: @JimB - it gets weirder. `zz = PDF[dist, x];
{Sum[zz, {x, 0, 6}] // N, Sum[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 6}] // N}` returns `{2.58266,1.}`.

Comment: @ciao.  Wow!  It does indeed get weirder!  `Sum[zz, {x, 0, 6, 3}]` gives 1 but  `Sum[zz, {x, 0, 6, 1}]` gives 2.58266.  Also, `zz := PDF[dist, x];
Sum[zz, {x, 0, 6}] // N` gives 1.

Comment: @JimB - Yes. And to be fair, it does say in the docs something along the lines of substituting values into symbolic PDF can result in nonsense, but the same happens with `PDF[dist,Range[0,6]]`, which the docs clearly state is a perfectly valid form, and should return exactly the same results as `PDF[dist, #] & /@ Range[0, 6]`. Not good.